# Coding Interview: What to model for OO demo?

Tags: php, class, oop, model

I am going in for a coding interview soon that is supposed to test my Object Oriented Programming concepts. I know about OO programming in great detail, my only problem is they asked that during the interview I show how to make an OO model on a whiteboard and gave me a Rubix cube or Guitar as past examples of what others have modeled for the interview.

My concern is doing something too simplistic like a Person Class and not conveying all the concepts I know. But I also don't want to pick something that abstract like a Rubix cube that my interviewer may hate the idea and question its practicality or extensibility. I also don't want to give him something he's seen before.

my first thought was to do something with fishing because its a real world example, and I enjoy it, but I wonder if it's too simple a concept. Like this as a quick example:

```
abstract class Fisherman {
  abstract protected function fish();
}

class Angler extends Fisherman {
  protected function fish() {
     $this->cast();
  }
  private function cast() {
    echo "Casting Rod";
  }
}

class CrabFisherman extends Fisherman {
  protected function fish() {
    $this->place();
  }
  private function place() {
     echo "Placing Crab Pot";
  }
}
```

So my question is, what should I model in an object oriented manner for a coding interview in order to best show understanding of OO concepts? Is it okay to do a simple person class, like with fisherman, or should I push the envelope? First real engineering interview so I'm not quite sure what to bring to the table.

Comment: Why not create an interview class?  Now you control the interview :-)

Comment: thats great idea! thats hilarious, and I bet they haven't seen that

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not a very good one because it is just straight inheritance. The examples they gave are systems with multiple objects connected by composition. A guitar has a body, strings and tuning pegs. The body contains both strings and tuning pegs. The tuning pegs can be set to change the note the string plays. Plus you could give the body different kinds of strings. And electric guitar adds pickups, volume controls, etc. The rubics cube similarly has a core, sides and cubes.

If you like fishing, perhaps better would be to model a fisher and fishing rod with tackle. The rod, reel, line, weight, float, hook and bait can all be changed with no change in the basic act of fishing. An equipped fisher could be deployed to different fishing locations, and the success would depend on the configuration.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to think about and answer my question, thats a great idea to use fishing gear in a collection, I was even thinking it could be gathered under a TackleBox class